# SQLAlchemy: Apply filter to a hybrid property build from a relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have an `Item` class and an `ItemPrice` class. An `Item` has many `ItemPrice`'s.

The `Item`'s price (a hybrid property) is the latest `ItemPrice` associated with its id.

Here's the code

```
class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "item"

    id_item = db.Column(db.Integer,
                        primary_key=True,
                        index=True,
                        unique=True)
    item_prices = db.relationship('ItemPrice', lazy='select', 
                                  backref('item', lazy='joined'))

    @hybrid_property
    def price(self):
        return self.item_prices[-1].price

    @price.expression
    def price(cls):
        return select([ItemPrice.price]) \
            .correlate(Item, ItemPrice) \
            .where(ItemPrice.id_item==cls.id_item) \
            .order_by(ItemPrice.created.desc()) \
            .limit(1)


class ItemPrice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "item_price"

    id_item_price = db.Column(db.Integer,
                              primary_key=True,
                              index=True,
                              unique=True)

    id_item = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('item.id_item'),
                        index=False,
                        nullable=False)

    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(),
                    index=True,
                    unique=False,
                    nullable=False)
```

I'm trying to run a filter on the `price` property

```
Item.query.join(ItemPrice).filter(Item.price >= 1).all()
```

and I'm getting this error which says that I can't do an int comparison with a `Select` object.

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Select' and 'int'
```

---

**Questions**

Is the error related to how I wrote `@price.expression` or the `filter`?

How would I change the `@price.expression` or `filter` to fix this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@price.expression
def price(cls):
    return select([ItemPrice.price]) \
        .correlate(Item, ItemPrice) \
        .where(ItemPrice.id_item==cls.id_item) \
        .order_by(ItemPrice.created.desc()) \
        .as_scalar()
```

For anyone else trying to debug a problem similar to this one, here's how I got it to something that worked:

1. I logged the query `Item.query.join(ItemPrice).filter(Item.price >= 1)`.
2. The subquery to find `discount_pct` was returning a list instead of a single value.
3. The way to return a single value instead of a list is with `as_scalar()`.